# Use Function from one controller to the other, possible?

Tags: controller, refresh, sapui5

I am currently stuck with something, nobody in the World might have ever had to do.

I have 3 Controllers, and i want the 3rd to use a function from the first.

here is how it looks:

this is my Master controller, it has a function called "onRefresh" which i want triggered.

This is the Detail Controller with a function call to the Dialog:

and this, finally is my ApprovalDialog controller, from which i want the ListRefresher to be executed for the Master View as soon as the confirm Button is triggered. I just don't know how this can be done, or if at all.

```
            openDialog: function(OBJID, bApprove, aPurchaseOrders) {
            var fnPromise = function(fnResolve, fnFailed) {
                var sApprovalText, sTitle;
                this._ChrId = OBJID;
                this._fnApproveActionFinished = fnResolve;
                this._fnApproveFailed = fnFailed;
                this._bApprove = bApprove;
                this._aPurchaseOrders = aPurchaseOrders;

// This doesnt work
                    Controller.Master.onRefresh();
```

### Do you know if there is an Answer ?

See Andrii's Answer, I think Im almost there :)

Thanks @Andrii-
here is the current situation:
from the SubControllerForApproval - Controller

SubController

[image: about SubController]

Code:

[image: about SubController - coding]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you using the event bus for this purpose:

The central event router will be your **component**, meaning you will trigger and listen events on the component instance.

It will look something like this:

**Master controller**:

somewhere in "**onInit**":

```
this.getOwnerComponent().attachEvent("ExternalMasterRefresh", this.onRefresh, this);
```

somewhere in **detail or dialog** controller:

```
this.getOwnerComponent().fireEvent("ExternalMasterRefresh");
```

these are methods of [EventProvider](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.EventProvider.html).

Comment: Hi Andrii, Thanks a lot,
I have just tried what you said, the problem i get now is thet on the "onInit" function, the "this.onRefresh()" function is not defined yet, do you have any Idea how i could get passed that ?

Comment: the app keeps loading

Comment: are you sure? Are we speaking about master controller? show the coding.

Comment: are you talking about the suggestion from webide? Actually it's not ideal and "undefined" stands for the returning value type, so you can ignore this and open the app. And see if any errors in console.

Comment: ok, Andrii.
I have done as you said. The App keeps loading endlessly, i guess i probably have to find out why on my own. I have used the following on the onInit function: this.getOwnerComponent().attachEvent("ExternalMasterRefresh", this.onRefresh(), this);

Comment: so: this.onRefresh()
instead of this.onRefresh. Is that correct ?

My onRefresh() function looks as follows:
   onRefresh : function () {

    this._oList.getBinding("items").refresh();
}

Comment: i get the following Error:

Uncaught TypeError: this.getOwnerComponent is not a function
    at constructor.onConfirmAction .....

Comment: 1. yes, you need to use a link to the function "this.onRefresh" but not the result of it's cal. 2. show the coding of you "onConfirmAction", looks like that there is missing context, and "this" is not the "controller's" "this"

Comment: who calls the "onConfirmAction" ? what is subcontroller? How do you use this subcontroller?

Comment: btw you can also use the global event bus.

Comment: Hi Andrii, just tried it on the Detail Controller, from which the Buttons are located. and it works, i just have to find a way to use it on the SubController, i dont know how yet,  but it worked on the Detail Controller

Comment: where this subcontroller gets instantiated ?

Comment: so in you case it will look like this: this._oParentView.getController().getOwnerComponent()

Comment: Thank you Andrii!

Answer (score 0):

You could use event bus as proposed by Andrii Naumovych, and it should work.

By the way, facing such an issue in sapui5 rather means that your model and databindings are not that good. An action triggered by the detail view could definitly update a model binded in the master view, and this would be the way to go.

sapui5 brings a strong databinding framework, with the idea to get rid of eventing ;)

Comment: if you are talking about the switched-on option "refreshAfterChange" - I agree, it will automatically update binding for the list bound to the same entityset that has been update.

Answer (score 0):

if you extend your first controller with the 3rd, the 3rd would inherit that onRefresh() Method

Within the developer guide there should be an example for that:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/95d113be50ae40d5b0b562b84d715227.html

if i understood it right the event bus is kind of overkill